# Add r square and equation on a scatter plot

Tags: r

My r² and equation doesn't show on my scatter plot using visreg function

```
library(visreg)
variable1_lm<- lm(variable1 ~ variable2, 
                data = PCA)
visreg(variable1_lm , "variable2", gg = TRUE)
```

What code should I use so it displays on top of it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should reproducible data with your code. Here is an example with the `iris` data set that comes with R:

```
library(visreg)
library(ggplot2)

SL.lm <- lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width, iris)
RSQ <- summary(SL.lm)$r.squared
visreg(SL.lm, gg=TRUE) + ggtitle(paste("R-Square =", round(RSQ, 4)))
```

[image: Plot]